# Query works when i put directly into Database but not via Query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the query i put into the database.  My mysql database is in UTC but my data in inputted into Eastern US

```
SET time_zone = '-6:00';
SELECT HOUR(created_at), count(*) AS sent
FROM tweets
WHERE created_at
BETWEEN CURDATE()
AND NOW()
GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)
ORDER BY HOUR(created_at)
```

My php looks like:

```
$q = "SET time_zone = '-6:00'; 
SELECT HOUR(created_at), count(*) AS sent FROM tweets
WHERE created_at
BETWEEN CURDATE()
AND NOW()
GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)
ORDER BY HOUR(created_at)";

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

echo "[".$row['HOUR(created_at)'].",".$row['sent']."],";
```

Is there any reason the direct insert into the db works fine and returns results while the php doesnt work at all.

Comment: you cant run 2 queries at once

Comment: How would i go about setting it up to work :/ new to php/mysql.

Comment: You will need to use multi_query to run two queries at once.